# Parametrizing UIView class property does not display view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to display a UIView in my viewController class. I call the initCard method from my `viewDidLoad` method in my viewController. The first function works, but the second does not. In the second version of the function the view that I am trying to display does not show up, but the rest of the program functions normally. What am I doing wrong?

method call from `viewDidLoad`, works:

```
[self initCard];

- (void) initCard {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Card1View_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:self.card1ContainerView];
    self.card1ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b1fv.png"];
    CGRect sFrame = CGRectMake(100, 100,
                               self.card1ContainerView.frame.size.width,
                               self.card1ContainerView.frame.size.height);
    self.card1ContainerView.frame = sFrame;
}
```

method call from `viewDidLoad`, does not work:

```
[self initCard:self.card1ContainerView cardImageView:self.card1ImageView];

- (void) initCard: (UIView*)cardContainerView cardImageView:(UIImageView*)cardImageView {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Card1View_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:cardContainerView];
    cardImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b1fv.png"];
    CGRect sFrame = CGRectMake(100, 100,
                               cardContainerView.frame.size.width,
                               cardContainerView.frame.size.height);
    cardContainerView.frame = sFrame;
}
```

Comment: call it from ViewDidAppear, as when you call it from viewDidLoad, your view is not initialized with actual frame, so it might be getting wrong frame size.

Comment: I assume that self.card1ContainerView is an IBOutlet connected in Card1View_iPhone.xib, where this view controller is the file's owner, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `self.card1ContainerView` is an `IBOutlet` connected in the card view nib, at the time you call the second example it has not been connected yet, as you only load the nib in the method itself. Thus you are passing `nil` as the parameter to the method. Loading the nib in that method sets `self.card1ContainerView` to be the view you're probably interested in, but at that point it's too late - the method continues to use the nil value that was passed in to it. Method arguments are passed by value so even though you change the pointer that you passed when calling, the method is using the value it copied at the time it was called. So you are adding a `nil` view into your view hierarchy, which does nothing.

If you need to parameterize the container view argument, remove the nib loading step from the method call and then ensure you've loaded the nib prior to calling it with the parameter `self.card1ContainerView`:

```
- (void)setupCard {
   [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Card1View_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
   [self setupCard:self.card1ContainerView  imageView:self.card1ImageView];
}

- (void) setupCard: (UIView*)cardContainerView cardImageView:(UIImageView*)cardImageView {
    [self.view addSubview:cardContainerView];
    cardImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b1fv.png"];
    CGRect sFrame = CGRectMake(100, 100,
                               cardContainerView.frame.size.width,
                               cardContainerView.frame.size.height);
    cardContainerView.frame = sFrame;
}
```

I changed the name from `init...` to `setup...` because methods starting with `init` have a specific role in most Objective-C frameworks.

Note that you must ensure you don't pass `nil` arguments to the parameterized method, either by loading nibs before calling or by instantiating views in code and passing them to the method. That's what the new `setupCard` method does.